# редиректы в htaccess со слешем на без

Tags: .htaccess

как настроить

Редирект с `https://www.opt-shopper.ru на https://opt-shopper.ru`

Также нужно настроить редирект с урлов в конце со слешем на без слеша или обратно.

```
с https://opt-shopper.ru/katalog/klatchi-i-koshelki/zhenskie/  на https://opt-shopper.ru/katalog/klatchi-i-koshelki/zhenskie
```